# Recreate an xkcd graph procedurally with your favorite plotting tool

Tags: popularity-contest, graphical-output

Lately there have been quite a [number of questions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11350/xkcd-style-graphs) regarding the [recreation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74878/create-xkcd-style-diagram-in-tex) of [xkcd](http://xkcd.com)-style graphs like the following one ([1064](http://xkcd.com/1064/)) in [various languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12675147/xkcd-style-graphs-in-r).

[image: http://xkcd.com/1064/]

Your goal is to recreate any existing xkcd comic as close to the original as possible. The comic has to have at least one simple graph or pie chart or similar element.

**The highest voted answer wins**, not sooner than 10 days after the first valid answer.

Your entry must contain code that displays an xkcd-comic as described above in a graphing language, making at least some use of its plotting tool (Mathematica, MatLab, etc.)

- the comic must not be stored as an image, it has to be generated procedulally
- there must not be any link whatsoever to the original website, or a mirror of it, or its contents on your hard drive, etc.

Votes should evaluate the similarity of the results to the original, and to a lesser extent, the beauty of the solution. No code golf here, but a solution as short and simple as possible is expected.

Comment: Most votes isn't a suitable [objective winning condition](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/faq) - and how are Boolean votes meant to take multiple elements into account to differing extents? I think this question can have an objective winning condition based on the average error per pixel divided by the code length or something similar, but as it stands it just encourages people to copy-paste the answers which have been heavily upvoted on other stacks.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: this is why I specified that it must be an **existing** xkcd comic, so there will be no copying. Most upvotes is a commonly used criteria (along with the "first solution", which I don't like that much), otherwise you would rarely find any problems here which are not code-golf (and not won by Golfscript)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a stab.

### Postscript

[*Count deleted because this isn't a golf question.*]

[image: xkcd1064]

Added a "style" section to make it look more hand-drawn.

[image: xkcd1064, more "hand-drawn"]

*Edit:* Helvetica responds better than Courier. Tweaked and enhanced this "style" section. And added comments.

[image: xkcd1064, even more "hand-drawn" than before]

```
%!

%futz with a coordinate pair
/f { 2 { rand 100 mod 100 div 1.47 mul
        dup .4 mul sub add
        exch } repeat } def

/op 2 array def %original point
/cp 2 array def %current point
/setcp { 2 copy cp astore pop } def %set current point
/difcp { cp aload pop %x' y' x y   %diff between cp and point on stack
    3 2 roll exch sub %x' x y'-y
    3 1 roll sub %y'-y x'-x
    exch %dx dy
} def
/scale2 { /n exch def  %scale two values
    n mul exch n mul exch
} def
/add2 {
    3 2 roll add
    3 1 roll add exch
} def
%futz with a path
/fpath {
    2 {
    %flattenpath
    % replace lines with curves
    [ { setcp cp op copy pop /moveto cvx }
        {
            %cp aload pop 4 2 roll 2 copy
            2 copy difcp %x3 y3 x30 y30
            2 copy 1 4 div scale2 %x3 y3 x30 y30 (1/3)x30 (1/3)y30
            cp aload pop add2 %x3 y3 x30 y30 x1 y1
            4 2 roll 3 4 div scale2 %x3 y3 x1 y1 (2/3)x30 (2/3)y30
            cp aload pop add2 %x3 y3 x1 y1 x2 y3
            6 4 roll %x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3
            setcp
            /curveto cvx }
        { setcp /curveto cvx }
        { op cp copy pop /closepath cvx } pathforall ] cvx newpath exec
    % chop the curves
    flattenpath
    % futz all the points
    [ { f
        /moveto cvx }
        { f
            /lineto cvx }
        { %f
            f 6 2 roll
            f 6 2 roll
            f 6 2 roll
            2 copy
            /curveto cvx
            3 1 roll
            3{f}repeat /lineto cvx % extra triple-futz'd line after each curve
        }
        { /closepath cvx } pathforall ] cvx newpath exec
    } repeat
} def

%futz with strokes
/oldstroke /stroke load def
/stroke { fpath oldstroke } def

%futz with fills
/oldfill /fill load def
/fill { fpath oldfill } def

%make sure rectstroke doesn't bypass being futzed with
/rectstroke {
    4 2 roll moveto
    1 index 0 rlineto
    0 exch rlineto
    neg 0 rlineto
    closepath
    stroke
} def

%futz with strings
%by making sure show uses our futz'd fill
/show { gsave currentpoint newpath moveto dup
    false charpath 1{fpath}repeat fill grestore stringwidth rmoveto } def

%fatter lines
1 setlinejoin %round joins
currentlinewidth 1.9 mul setlinewidth
%chop curves very small so there's lots of points for futzing
currentflat 6 div setflat

/Helvetica 10 selectfont

<<
/in{72 mul}
>>begin
1 in 1 in translate

0 0 6 in 4 in rectstroke
1 in 3 in moveto (WALKING BACK TO MY) show
1 in 2.8 in moveto (FRONT DOOR AT NIGHT:) show

36 3.5 in moveto
0 -2.8 in rlineto
5 in 0 rlineto
3.45 in .55 in moveto
0 20 rlineto
4.05 in .55 in moveto
0 20 rlineto
2.7 in .40 in moveto
(YARD  STEPS DOOR  INSIDE ) show
0 .05 in rmoveto
.4 in 0 rlineto
currentpoint
stroke
moveto
-10 3 rlineto
0 -6 rlineto fill

2.6 in .45 in moveto
-2 in 0 rlineto
currentpoint
stroke
moveto
10 3 rlineto
0 -6 rlineto fill

(FEAR) .9 in 2.3 in moveto show
(THAT THERE'S) .9 in 2.1 in moveto show
(SOMETHING) .9 in 1.9 in moveto show
(BEHIND ME) .9 in 1.7 in moveto show
1.8 in 1.86 in moveto
2 -26 rlineto
stroke

(FORWARD) 2.2 in 2.1 in moveto show
(SPEED) 2.2 in 1.9 in moveto show
2.75 in 2 in moveto
3 -13 rlineto
stroke

(EMBARRASSMENT) 4.5 in 2.5 in moveto show
4.6 in 2.65 in moveto
-2 20
-5 22
-27 25 rcurveto
stroke

.6 setgray %gray
40 1.6 in moveto
2.7 in 0
2.9 in 20
3.2 in 1.5 in rcurveto
10 20
20 20
30 0 rcurveto
15 -1.7 in
30 -1.8 in
1.4 in -2 in rcurveto
stroke

0 0 1 setrgbcolor %blue
40 1.2 in moveto
.9 in 27
.8 in 20
1.4 in 21 rcurveto
1 in -20
1.2 in 6
1.3 in 1.6 in rcurveto
    10 20
    20 20
    30 0 rcurveto
15 -1.8 in
30 -1.9 in
1.8 in -2.1 in rcurveto
stroke

1 0 0 setrgbcolor %red
40 .9 in moveto
3.3 in 0
3.5 in 20
3.6 in 1.5 in rcurveto
10 72
20 80
30 80 rcurveto
.7 in -10
.3 in -35
1.1 in -40 rcurveto
stroke

%thank you for scrolling all the way down to here. :)
```

Comment: can you add some of the "hand-drawn" stylization to it? :)

Comment: Yes. I completely overlooked that aspect at first. And then when I followed the links I was completely overwhelmed. Fat lines should be no biggie. And I've got a method from Casselman to reinterpret a path. So if I can understand those mathematica transforms, I should be able to replicate them. A much bigger task than I originally thought.

Comment: Even without those qualities, a very very good job.

Comment: And super great job on the styling!

Answer (score 6):

## HTML5

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Humor Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Humor Sans'), local('Humor Sans-Regular'), url("data:font/woff;base64,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") format('woff');
}
body {
    font-family: 'Humor Sans';
    margin: 2em;
    background: #DDD;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #FFF;
}
h1 {
    font-family:Lucida,Helvetica,sans-serif;
}
.h1d {
    display: inline;
    font-size: .8em;
}
path,rect { fill: none;
    stroke:#000000;
    stroke-width:0.00329859;
    stroke-linecap:butt;
    stroke-linejoin:round;
    stroke-miterlimit:10.43299961;
 }
text {
    text-align:start;
    letter-spacing:0px;
    word-spacing:0px;
    writing-mode:lr-tb;
    font-size:14px;
    text-anchor:start;
    fill:#000000;
    fill-opacity:1;
    stroke:none;
    font-family:Humor Sans;
}
text {
    font-size:0.01944444px;
    text-anchor:middle;
    fill:#000000;
    fill-opacity:1;
    stroke:none;
    font-family:Humor Sans;
}
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<title>Front Door ( from xkcd.com 1064 )</title>
  </head>
<body><h1>Front Door <div class="h1d">( from xkcd.com 1064 )</div></h1>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="640" height="434"
   version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 0.7876308 0.53355077">
  <defs>
    <marker id="Aen" style="overflow:visible">
      <path d="M 0,0 5,-5 -12.5,0 5,5 0,0 z" transform="matrix(-0.4,0,0,-0.4,-4,0)"
         style="fill-rule:evenodd;fill:#000;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1pt" />
    </marker>
    <marker orient="auto" id="Ast" style="overflow:visible">
      <path d="M 0,0 5,-5 -12.5,0 5,5 0,0 z"
         transform="matrix(-0.4,0,0,-0.4,-1.4,0)"
         style="fill-rule:evenodd;fill:#000;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1pt" />
    </marker>
  </defs>
  <rect width="0.75612795" height="0.50201935" x="0.015758738" y="0.015780471" />
  <path d="m 0.08162198,0.08036774 c -3.384e-4,3.2166e-4 -7.6617e-4,0.35262886 -7.6617e-4,0.35262886 0,0 0.20318503,-6.6026e-4 0.29000566,-0.003213 0.0402085,3.6731e-4 0.0806898,-1.3866e-4 0.12100339,-4.2191e-4 0.0422491,-4.676e-5 0.0848177,0.001196 0.12714108,1.4026e-4 0.0292134,0.0012 0.0579496,7.8663e-4 0.0872307,8.041e-5" />
  <path d="M 0.45045642,0.44967094 C 0.45097434,0.43767424 0.44992661,0.42569324 0.4498655,0.41370014" />
  <path d="m 0.52462262,0.44857719 c 0.001364,-0.0112841 -0.001303,-0.022673 8.8508e-4,-0.0339046" />
  <path d="m 0.34455432,0.46185837 c -0.0838098,-0.00177 -0.16763839,9.02e-5 -0.25145536,-4.499e-4" style="marker-end:url(#Ast)" />
  <path d="m 0.36372087,0.26833529 c 3.15e-6,-3.093e-5 0.003925,0.021959 0.003958,0.0219625" />
  <path d="m 0.59455272,0.18635665 c 0.00168,-0.0249062 -0.0194278,-0.0449558 -0.0436226,-0.042955 -0.001466,-1.5486e-4 -0.002932,-3.0973e-4 -0.004398,-4.6459e-4" />
  <path d="m 0.08896568,0.31883844 c 0.0589995,-0.004388 0.11835478,4.8486e-4 0.17689559,-0.007727 0.0452821,-0.002558 0.0920316,-0.008761 0.13292997,-0.0296799 0.0495136,-0.0206019 0.0702543,-0.0754087 0.082167,-0.12423165 -0.001544,-0.0316524 0.0363005,-0.0771322 0.0574533,-0.031946 0.009799,0.0468904 0.0124403,0.0957944 0.0257953,0.14199884 0.0103229,0.0424564 0.0381648,0.0821154 0.0814383,0.0955288 0.0230248,0.006738 0.0463641,0.0136174 0.0701731,0.01698" style="stroke:#888" />
  <path d="m 0.08766361,0.36678952 c 0.0463076,-0.0161779 0.0920382,-0.0420708 0.14283849,-0.0357173 0.0467333,-0.004581 0.0974621,0.0266481 0.14082991,-0.00179 0.0400306,-0.0301432 0.041483,-0.0866619 0.0490443,-0.13214834 0.003929,-0.030081 -0.00375,-0.0999028 0.0422392,-0.0879794 0.0291414,0.0376662 0.0177989,0.0902038 0.0319018,0.1336763 0.009362,0.0507676 0.0330856,0.10817744 0.0871312,0.12415282 0.0508722,0.0193263 0.0767224,0.0174745 0.11889504,0.0257316" style="stroke:#00f" />
  <path d="m 0.08912193,0.4046365 c 0.10169167,1.097e-5 0.2041028,3.5438e-4 0.3047905,-0.0155419 0.0458292,-0.008171 0.0971567,-0.0242812 0.12178371,-0.0670869 0.025388,-0.0534434 0.0183231,-0.11451516 0.0333489,-0.17061477 -0.003977,-0.0433016 0.0436224,-0.0993166 0.0831427,-0.0568712 0.0246552,0.0226559 0.0477548,0.0560862 0.0858377,0.0521295" style="stroke:#f00" />
  <path d="m 0.70840577,0.46185837 c -0.002849,8.248e-5 -0.0849355,0.001616 -0.0849355,0.001616" style="marker-start:url(#Aen)" />
  <path d="m 0.24465913,0.2858699 c 9.6794e-4,0.0147144 0.001383,0.0294673 0.002814,0.0441494" />
  <text x="100.15588" y="48.485607" transform="scale(0.00138889,0.00138889)"
    style="font-size:14px;text-anchor:start">
    <tspan x="100.15588" y="48.485607" id="tspan7010">WALKING BACK TO MY</tspan>
    <tspan x="100.15588" y="65.285591" id="tspan7012">FRONT DOOR AT NIGHT:</tspan></text>
  <rect width="0.24843951" height="0.065260872" x="0.12345294" y="0.039088331" />
  <text x="0.23551519" y="0.20231472"><tspan x="0.23551519" y="0.20231472">fear</tspan>
    <tspan x="0.23551519" y="0.22564805">ThAT there's</tspan>
    <tspan x="0.23551519" y="0.24898137">something</tspan>
    <tspan x="0.23551519" y="0.2723147">behing me</tspan></text>
  <text x="0.36015913" y="0.22917171"><tspan x="0.36015913" y="0.22917171">fORWarD</tspan>
    <tspan x="0.36015913" y="0.25250503">SPEED</tspan></text>
  <text x="0.37393194" y="0.46812996"><tspan x="0.37393194" y="0.46812996">yarD</tspan>
    <tspan x="0.45037103" y="0.46812996">step</tspan>
    <tspan x="0.52267832" y="0.46812996">door</tspan>
    <tspan x="0.58878779" y="0.46812996">inside</tspan></text>
  <text x="0.63905853" y="0.20506927">
    <tspan x="0.63905853" y="0.20506927">emBARRASSMENT</tspan></text>
</svg>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 6):

## Python

Makes use of the slightly cheat-y xkcd method in matplotlib:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.ndimage.filters import gaussian_filter1d

plt.xkcd()

x = np.linspace(0,10,1000)
unit = np.linspace(0,1,100)

speed = np.r_[np.ones(500)*3,3+5*unit**4.,np.ones(100)*8,1+7*unit[::-1]**2,np.ones(200)]
speed = gaussian_filter1d(speed,18)

fear = np.r_[np.linspace(0.5,2,450),2+6*unit**4,np.ones(100)*8,8*unit[::-1]**2,np.zeros(250)+0.1]
fear = gaussian_filter1d(fear,18)
fear_gauss_bump = 0.8*np.exp(-np.power(x-2.5,2.)/(2*np.power(1, 2.)))
fear += fear_gauss_bump

embarrassment = np.r_[np.zeros(600)+0.1, 9.5*unit**2, 9.5-np.linspace(0,1.5,300)]
embarrassment = gaussian_filter1d(embarrassment,60)

plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))
plt.plot(x,speed,c="gray")
plt.plot(x,fear,c="#1E9FDB")
plt.plot(x,embarrassment,c="r")

plt.plot([2.5,2.7],[3.9,2.3],c='k')
plt.plot([4.3,4.5],[3.6,3.1],c='k')
plt.plot(np.linspace(7.3,7.8,15),(0.25-(np.linspace(7.3,7.8,15)-7.3)**2)**0.5+7,c='k')

ax = plt.gca()
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.get_xaxis().tick_bottom()
ax.get_yaxis().tick_left()
#plt.ylim([0,10])
ax.set_xticks([6,7])
ax.set_xticklabels(["STEPS","DOOR"])
ax.set_yticks([])

ax.text(2,4,"FEAR\nTHAT THERE'S\nSOMETHING\nBEHIND ME",horizontalalignment='center')
ax.text(3.9,3.4,"FORWARD\nSPEED",horizontalalignment='center')
ax.text(7.4,6.6,"EMBARRASSMENT")
ax.text(1,8,"WALKING BACK TO MY\nFRONT DOOR AT NIGHT:",bbox={'facecolor':'none', 'edgecolor':'black'})
ax.annotate("YARD", xy=(0.5,-0.3), xytext=(4.5,-0.4),annotation_clip=False,arrowprops={'facecolor':'black', 'shrink':0.01, 'width':0.5})
ax.annotate("INSIDE", xy=(10,-0.3), xytext=(7.5,-0.4),annotation_clip=False,arrowprops={'facecolor':'black', 'shrink':0.01, 'width':0.5})

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Upvoted - literally never knew there was an xkcd function in matplotlib.